# how the wiki site work i mean the sql structure

Tags: mysql, data-structures, wiki

any one know
that in wiki sites
any one can edit the page
i want know
how i can make this is mysql
i want to know the mysql table structure fot that job
and how approve edits

Comment: Data base structure is described here: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_layout. Most detailed diagram is http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/33/MediaWiki_database_schema_1-19_(r102798).svg/2193px-MediaWiki_database_schema_1-19_(r102798).svg.png

Answer (score 2):

That's an extremely broad question — almost like asking, "What tables should I have for an e-commerce site?" It depends entirely on what content you want to store.

If you want to know more about a particular wiki implementation (e.g., MediaWiki, which powers Wikipedia), you can simply download and install the application. The actual tables with real data in them will then be right there for you to look through at your leisure.

If you're designing a new wiki application, you'll have to know a lot more about the data involved before you can begin to define a table structure.

In general, though, any time you want to store a history of revisions, you'll need a table representing revisions. Each row in this table stores the text of a revision, and a foreign key connects it to the page (or other object) it's a revision of.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look to the [Mediawiki data base schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mediawiki_dbschema.svg):

[click here for the full size image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Mediawiki_dbschema.svg/2000px-Mediawiki_dbschema.svg.png)

[image: Mediawiki data base schema]

Answer (score 0):

You can have a table containing pages and a table containing page history (with a PageID foreign key)